# Intel Edison Ubilinux as distro I am getting FAILED Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdrmdir[ctrl_interface]: No such file or directory

Tags: wifi, intel, access-point

I am attempting to setup my Intel Edison WiFi as an Access Point.  The Edison is running Ubilinux as the distro. I followed this forum post to setup the Edison as an Access Point: https://communities.intel.com/message/278220  I am now receiving this Failed message:

[....] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdrmdir[ctrl_interface]: No such file or directory

I am not sure why I am receiving that Failed message? How do I setup my Edison as an Access Point?

Comment: The answer to your question has now been added to the original thread in the Intel forums you've linked to: You need to compile hostapd on the Edison and replace the default install of hostapd with it, as the version shipping with Ubilinux doesn't properly supports access point functionality on Edison.